# lead/lag function in apache PIG

Tags: sql, apache-pig

Is there a function in apache PIG that's similar to Lead/Lag function in SQL? Or any pig function that can look back to previous row of record?

Comment: @DonaldMiner Hey Donald would you be able to provide any links to where I can get started with this?

Comment: I've recently done Lag and Lead in MapReduce and by using Secondary Sorting, which obviates the problems from the shared nothing approach, as all values for a given key get sent to the correct reducer and are ordered. I'll see what I can cook up for a UDF.

Comment: @DonaldMiner Would you mind checking out my answers and give me some feed back?

Comment: Ignore comments about this not being possible. See answer below by @user3062149.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an alternative:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
import org.apache.pig.data.DataType;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;
import org.apache.pig.data.TupleFactory;
import org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException;
import org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.schema.Schema;
import org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.schema.Schema.FieldSchema;

public class GenericLag2 extends EvalFunc<Tuple>{

    private List<String> lagObjects = null;

    @Override
    public Tuple exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        if (lagObjects == null) {
            lagObjects = new ArrayList<String>();
            return null;
        }
        try {
            Tuple output = TupleFactory.getInstance().newTuple(lagObjects.size());
            for (int i = 0; i < lagObjects.size(); i++) {
                output.set(i, lagObjects.get(i));
            }

            lagObjects.clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
                lagObjects.add(input.get(i).toString());
            }
            return output;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Schema outputSchema(Schema input) {
        Schema tupleSchema = new Schema();
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
                tupleSchema.add(new FieldSchema("lag_" + i, DataType.CHARARRAY));
            }
            return new Schema(new FieldSchema(getSchemaName(this.getClass().getName().toLowerCase(), input), tupleSchema, DataType.TUPLE));
        } catch (FrontendException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I assume this would be faster, but I'm not sure, as you would have to do the following:

```
... 
C = ORDER A BY important_order_by_field, second_important_order_by_field
D = FOREACH B GENERATE
    important_order_by_field
    ,second_important_order_by_field
    ,...
    ,FLATTEN(LAG(
        string_field_to_lag
        ,int_field_to_lag
        ,date_field_to_lag
    ))
    ;
E = FOREACH D GENERATE
    important_order_by_field
    ,second_important_order_by_field
    ,...
    ,string_field_to_lag
    ,(int) int_field_to_lag
    ,(date_field_to_lag IS NULL ? 
        null :
        ToDate(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(date_field_to_lag, 'T', ' '), 0, 19),  'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) 
        as date_field_to_lag
;
DUMP E;
```

Comment: Accepted answer should be answer by @user3062149.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is pre-defined functionality. See the [Over()](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/evaluation/Over.html) and [Stitch()](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/evaluation/Stitch.html) methods in Piggybank. Over() has examples listed in the documentation.

Comment: This is much more convenient. It includes the functionality pre-built. Good find!

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is my first shot at this. Mind you, I just started learning how to code UDFs today.

Maven's pom.xml file contains:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
  <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-cdh4.1.0</version>
</dependency>
...
```

Java UDF Class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;

public class GenericLag extends EvalFunc<String>{

    private String lagObject = null;

    @Override
    public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        try {
            String returnObject = getLagObject();
            setLagObject(input.get(0).toString());
            return returnObject;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String getLagObject() {
        return lagObject;
    }
    public void setLagObject(String lagObject) {
        this.lagObject = lagObject;
    }

}
```

Initially, I had used `Object` instead of `String` everywhere that you see "String" above, but I received this error:

`ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2080: Foreach currently does not handle type Unknown`

I had to issue `setLagObject(input.get(0).toString());` instead of `setLagObject(input.get(0);` or I would have received errors like:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

`java.lang.ClassCastException: org.joda.time.DateTime cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

Here is how I use it in Pig:

```
REGISTER /path/to/compiled/file.jar
DEFINE LAG fully.qualified.domain.name.GenericLag();

A = LOAD '/hdfs/path/to/directory' USING PigStorage(',') AS (
    important_order_by_field:int
    ,second_important_order_by_field:string
    ,...
    ,string_field_to_lag:string
    ,int_field_to_lag:int
    ,date_field_to_lag:string
);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE
    important_order_by_field
    ,second_important_order_by_field
    ,...
    ,string_field_to_lag
    ,int_field_to_lag
    ,ToDate(date_field_to_lag, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
    ;
C = ORDER A BY important_order_by_field, second_important_order_by_field
D = FOREACH B GENERATE
    important_order_by_field
    ,second_important_order_by_field
    ,...
    ,LAG(string_field_to_lag) AS lag_string
    ,(int) LAG(int_field_to_lag) AS lag_int
    ,(date_field_to_lag IS NULL ? 
        null : 
        ToDate(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(LAG(date_field_to_lag), 'T', ' ') ,0,19), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) AS lag_date
    ;
DUMP D;
```

If I did the last line like this:

`ToDate(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(LAG(date_field_to_lag), 'T', ' ') ,0,19), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') AS lag_date`

It would return the following error

`ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias LAGGED_RHODES. Backend error : null`

Which when checking the logs reveals:

`java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$NumberFormatter.parseInto(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:1200)`

because the first row will contain a null value.